# Managing different models within the same Controller in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a Comment model which morphs to many models. When I add a comment, I want to the use the same Controller, like so:

```
Route::post('/user/{user}/comments', 'CommentController@store')
Route::post('/team/{team}/comments', 'CommentController@store')
```

How do I differentiate the models in the *store* method? Right now, it seems like this would be the best option:

```
public function store(Request $request, User $user = null, Team $team = null) 
{ 
    $parent = null;
    if ($user !== null) { $parent = $user; }
    if ($team !== null) { $parent = $team; } 
    // etc for all models, cumbersome and ugly....

    $parent->comment('foo');
}
```

I know I could also use different methods in the *CommentController*, i.e. `storeOnUser(Request $request, User $user) {}`, but Is there any better way to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for extra route for each commentable

you just need to pass the commentable_id and and commentable_type in each form

```
 $Commentable ="App\".ucfirst($request->input('commentable_type'));

 $commentable =$Commentable::findOrFail($request->input('commentable_id'));

 $commentable->comments()->save($comment);
```

put data in hidden input

```
<input value="{{$model->id}}" type="hidden" name="commentable_id">
<input value="modelName" type="hidden" name="commentable_type">
```

Comment: Instead of using form input, i chose to change up the route a bit: `Route::post('/comments/{type}/{id}', 'CommentController@store')` and the store function: `public function store(Request $request, $type, $id) {}`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assume `{user}` and `{team}` is the `primary id` of corresponding table.

```
public function store(Request $request, $id) 
{ 
     $parent = null;
      if($request->route('user')) { 
            $parent = User::find($id); 
        }
      if($request->route('team')){
            $parent = Team::find($id); 
         } 
      // etc for all models, cumbersome and ugly....

       $parent->comment('foo');
}
```